# A while loop with multiple conditions joined by an "and"

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am running into difficulty getting the syntax of my loop to run, but when I ran each of the expressions in a different line it came out to be "true."

The line of code is as follows, but the error I am getting is "unexpected EOF while parsing"

```
for dayindx in range(0, maxdays):
    actives_df.sort_values('CurrentStatus')
    i=0
    while i < len(actives_df.index) and actives_df.at[i, 'CurrentStatus']=='Active':
```

Comment: What's the while loop there for? You need to have statements after the `:` that you want to loop over. It isn't clear though what your intent is with the loop.

Comment: This while loop is nested within a loop over days. Every day we're going to have a different status value for each row in the dataframe. Hence we only want to loop over active people.

Comment: @user12852903 The `while` loop as written is not valid Python. As mentioned above, you _need_ to have a statement within the loop body. Does adding `pass` to the block following the `while` statement fix your issue?

Comment: I added pass, but the new error is "'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: That sounds like a different and mostly unrelated error. We probably can't fix it just from an error message, you really should give the full stack trace. But I'm not sure it's a good idea to edit a different issue into this one. Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to get interactive debugging help of a whole program. Its format really expects one question to stand by itself (though if you have more issues later, you can ask them separately as their own questions, perhaps with links back to previous questions to give context). Please check out the [help] and [ask].